# Knockout VIewModel triggers function inside foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am fighting with strange issue and i am running out of ideas.

The problem is that my view model is triggering function inside foreach on click. So in this case if i click on div menuConnections testcall function is being triggered. Even if i send other value to testcall (such as div id) same value is being sent when I click on menuConnections.

How to stop this and force testcall to be executed only when i click on TheDivWhoCalls?

```js
function ProfileViewModel(userId) {
    var self = this;
  
    self.connectionRequests = ko.observableArray();

  self.getConnections = function () {
        $("#menuConnections").css({ "display": "block" });
    
    //other code which returns data
    };
  
  self.testcall = function(data) {
        alert(target);
    };;
    
  }
```

```html
<div id="menuConnections" data-bind='click: getConnections'>Connections</div>

<div id="connections" style="display: none">
  
  <div data-bind="foreach: connectionRequests">
    
    <div id="TheDivWhoCalls" data-bind='click: $root.testcall("asd")'><img src="~/Resources/Images/yesIcon.png" /></div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Not your problem here but this would generate multiple instances of `#TheDivWhoCalls`. Element ids should be uinique on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell for sure without seeing an actual running example with `ko.applyBindings` but try changing

```
data-bind='click: $root.testcall("asd")
```

to

```
 data-bind='click: $parent.testcall.bind($parent, "asd")
```

Explanation:

First I changed `$root` to `$parent`. I don't know what your `$root` is, but its safe to assume that your `$parent` is the VM with the `testcall` method.

More importantly, is that `click:` expects a function, but `$root.testcall("asd")` invokes the function returning `undefined`. Instead we use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function from `testcall` with the parameter set to `"asd"`and `this` set to `$parent`

Comment: @Goran added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You might need the bind syntax instead. Try `data-bind="$root.testcall.bind($data, 'asd')"`

Comment: Nope, it is not calling testcall at all after I change to this.

Comment: @Goran, sorry I left out the `.bind`